# How can I make HttpClient works faster?

Tags: android, get, apache-commons-httpclient

I have an application that posts to and gets from a PHP and MySQL server. I used this function all with GET actions but it took about 5 seconds. I used `HttpParams` but it didn't work, too.

Is there any way to make it faster?

```
String responseBine(){
    Log.d("destpek wext","");
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget= new HttpGet(urlIndex);
        if(logged) {
            HttpResponse rs = httpclient.execute(Teketin.httppost, localContext);
            EntityUtils.toString(rs.getEntity());
            rs = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
            EntityUtils.toString(rs.getEntity());
        }
        responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String rsp = new String(httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
        return rsp;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("destpek wext","");
    return  "";
}
```

Comment: if you "think" it is slow try the std `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and compare the their execution time

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues as yours until I discovered Volley(android library for http requests). Using Volley helped reducing some seconds.

Still not satisfied as my queries were taking about 2 to 3 seconds, I switched to Node.js + MySQL and it brought down the timing to around 200 milliseconds!